# value changed eventhandler

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, event-handling

I want to react, whenever an integer value has changed. So, is there a possibility to write an own eventhandler? I need to get the old value and the new one, because I have to de-reference some events for an object in a list with the index of the old value and reference these events to the listitem with the index of the new value.

Something like this (really abstract):

```
value.Changed += new Eventhandler(valuechanged);
private void valuechanged(object sender, eventargs e)
{
     list[e.Oldvalue] -= some eventhandler;
     list[e.newValue] += some eventhanlder;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677854/notifypropertychanged-event-where-event-args-contain-the-old-value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class ValueChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
     public readonly int LastValue;
     public readonly int NewValue;

     public ValueChangedEventArgs(int LastValue, int NewValue)
     {
         this.LastValue = LastValue;
         this.NewValue = NewValue;
     }
}

class Values
{
     public Values(int InitialValue)
     { 
          _value = InitialValue;
     }

     public event EventHandler<ValueChangedEventArgs> ValueChanged;

     protected virtual void OnValueChanged(ValueChangedEventArgs e)
     {
           if(ValueChanged != null)
              ValueChanged(this, e);
     }

     private int _value;

     public int Value
     {
         get { return _value; }
         set 
         {
             int oldValue = _value;
             _value = value;
             OnValueChanged(new ValueChangedEventArgs(oldValue, _value));
         }
     }
}
```

So you can use your class like here (*Console Test*):

```
void Main()
{
     Values test = new Values(10);

     test.ValueChanged += _ValueChanged;

     test.Value = 100;
     test.Value = 1000;
     test.Value = 2000;
}

void _ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
     Console.WriteLine(e.LastValue.ToString());
     Console.WriteLine(e.NewValue.ToString());
}
```

This will print:

```
Last Value: 10
New Value:  100

Last Value: 100
New Value: 1000

Last Value: 1000
New Value: 2000
```

Comment: @roqstr No, you can't inherit from value-types.

Comment: @Fuex Should you click on the edit you would see the comment about why I suggested it.  You had the opportunity to reject it.  And sure your current example in `_ValueChanged` isn't accessing the property itself, but should some other usage choose to cast `sender` and access the `Value` property it would still be the old value rather than the new value.

Comment: @natephette Damn you're right, for a while I forgot the sender. My apolagies and thank you very much for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

The only things that comes close is the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and[`INotifyPropertyChanging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanging.aspx) interfaces. These define the `PropertyChanged` & `PropertyChanging` events respectively.

However, these won't give you the new or old value, just that it has changed/changing.

You typically define them on properties.. ala:

```
private int _myInt;
public int MyInt
{
    get
    {
        return this._myInt;
    }

    set
    {
        if(_myInt == value)
            return;

        NotifyPropertyChanging("MyInt");    
        this._myInt = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("MyInt");
        }
    }
}
```

Note: `NotifyPropertyChanging()` & `NotifyPropertyChanged()` are just private methods that invoke the events.