# Is it possible to get old value and new value using NotifyPropertyChanged attribute of PostSharp, in PorpertyChanged event handler

Tags: postsharp

I need to capture old and new value in PropertyChanged event handler. I have already implemented a solution for this using C# INotifyPropertyChanged interface. 
You can refer below question for solution that I have implemented:

[How to capture old value and new value in INotifyPropertyChanged implementation of PropertyChanged event in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723876/how-to-capture-old-value-and-new-value-in-inotifypropertychanged-implementation)

I was evaluating if this can be done using PostSharp. Because with current solution, auto properties will not work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Umesh

Answer (score 0):

By definition `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface deals with notification *AFTER* the value has changed and `INotifyPropertyChanging` interface deals with notification *BEFORE* the value has changed. `[NotifyPropertyChanged]` aspect implements both for you but does not provide a way to do what you want out of the box.

Further it postpones notifications until a more complex change on the same object, this both lowers number of notifications and makes sure that when notification occurs, the object is in correct state (think of a method changing several properties on the object) for the code that reacts to the notification (this does not apply to `INotifyPropertyChanging`). More about the implementation details [here](http://doc.postsharp.net/inotifypropertychanged-conceptual).

You would need to implement an aspect that would implement your interface and would register itself for `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanging`, recording property values on each *changing* notification and using those recorded values on *changed* notification to raise your own event.

You would probably need to do the following:

- [introduce an interface](http://doc.postsharp.net/code-injections)
- [use instance-level aspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-lifetime)
- [initialize instance of the aspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-initialization)
- [get a property value](http://doc.postsharp.net/members)
- [dynamically add the underlying aspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-provider)
- [order aspects correctly](http://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-dependencies)

It does not seem as a complex aspect but you would definitely need to familiarize yourself with advanced concepts of PostSharp's Aspect Framework.