# How can I append a call to an extension method on a call to an async method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a custom extension method "ToSelectList" and I am currently using it like so:

```
        var myList = await _myService.GetItems();
        var mySelectList = myList.ToSelectList(nameof(MyEntity.Id));
```

That's fine and works great, however, I tried to do this as one line:

```
        var myList = await _myService.GetItems().ToSelectList(nameof(MyEntity.Id));
```

But I get:

```
'Task<List<MyEntity>>' does not contain a definition for 'ToSelectList'
and no extension method 'ToSelectList' accepting a first argument of type
'Task<List<MyEntity>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive 
or an assembly reference?)
```

My ToSelectList method is as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace MyProject.Extensions
{
    public static class ListExtensions
    {
        public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this List<T> list, string id, string text = "Name")
        {
            var selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

            list.ForEach(item =>
            {
                selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = item.GetType().GetProperty(text).GetValue(item).ToString(),
                    Value = item.GetType().GetProperty(id).GetValue(item).ToString()
                });
            });

            return selectListItems;
        }
    }
```

I tried changing method signature to `public async static Task<List<SelectListItem>>` but no joy.

Comment: `(await _myService.GetItems()).ToSelectList(nameof(MyEntity.Id))`

Comment: While @DavidG's comment is correct, that's actually pretty bad. Don't get all data from the database to project only a small part. Make the service call return only the required data

Comment: `ToSelectList` could be replaced by a `Select(it=>new SelectListItem{Text="id",Value=>it.id});`. You don't need reflection for that. If you wanted the name/value pair for serialization, simply selecting the value would work. XML and Json serializers would discover the property name and construct the correct XML or JSON string.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto why is this bad? The db table contains an id and a name column and a list of items i need to return to a dropdown list. I always need the entire contents of this table to populate my dropdown.

Comment: In that case that's not a problem, but since you didn't post your models this could have been a table with many columns

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the suggestion. Text="id" needs to be Text=it.Name (what does it stand for? item?)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I see what you mean. I may add columns in future so I will keep this in mind. What would you name the GetItems method if it changed to only get Id and Name columns? GetItemNameValuePairs ?

Comment: @egmfrs `it` means `it`, the english word. It's just a parameter name. LINQ already does what you attempt. All LINQ methods accept Expressions that specify conditions, selections, properties etc. The same trick is used to implement generic property change handlers, as shown [in the third example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677854/notifypropertychanged-event-where-event-args-contain-the-old-value).

Comment: @egmfrs Quite often though you'll realize that making your code too generic or model-driven results in *more hardwiring* than just using what's available. Hence the question, why do you want this?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos to save me having to repeat the code to build a select list every time I want to populate a dropdown in my view model. I have about 5 tables, each containing a list of options for a form, essentially. The number of questions on the form may grow, and there will be more tables with more options. On the post action, if the model validation fails, the dropdowns need to be repopulated to the view model again. So the majority of my controller code seemed to be building and re-building select lists all over the place.

Comment: @egmfrs then your actual problem is a form that can display editors for any property in a DTO, eg an editable Card view. That's not as easy as it looks. After a while you'll find out that you *have* to be able to customize individual fields. And what about *validation*? Annotations? You may end up writing a *lot* more code with the *generic* solution than sending the entity as a `Model` to the view and writing the `EditorFor` statements.

Comment: @egmfrs You should probably look for a control or widget to do that before trying to roll your own. There are many (possibly too many) such *Javascript* controls and jQuery plugins, form builders for ASP.NET MVC etc. Commercial packages like those offered by Telerik, Devexpress etc. cost but can save you a *lot* of time, since they've already implemented the tricky parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `await` applies to the entire line so you either need to wrap it in parentheses:

```
var myList = (await _myService.GetItems())
    .ToSelectList(nameof(MyEntity.Id));
```

Or split it onto 2 lines:

```
var items = await _myService.GetItems();
var myList = items.ToSelectList(nameof(MyEntity.Id));
```

Comment: parentheses - thats what I needed, thanks. I'm not sure if the call to GetItems even needs to be async. It returns results of a query to the db.

Comment: If it's doing DB calls, then yes, that should be async.

Answer (score 1):

While [@DavidG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663001/davidg)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51310964/2141621) is correct, I would suggest you to simplify your logic. You don't need any of that reflection code if you use the built-in `Tuple<T1, T2>`:

```
// let's assume this is in your service class
// you most likely want a better name
public Task<List<Tuple<int, string>>> GetItemsAsEnumAsync()
{
    return _context.SomeTable
        .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Id, x.Name))
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Your `ToSelectList` would then just be:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList(this List<Tuple<int, string>> list)
{
    return list
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.Item1.ToString(),
            Text = x.Item2
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

This assumes that your service is not in the same project as the ASP.NET Core application and hence cannot return the `List<SelectListItem>` itself. You could make `ToSelectList` more generic by using `ToSelectList<T1, T2>(this List<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>> list)` if you find it useful.

Comment: That's very much appreciated. Which part of my code is using reflection? The NameOf() parts? The fields for the select list are not fixed. My db conventions are SomeTableId rather than just Id. And Name is not always Name. How would I call it if I use the T1, T2 version?

Comment: @egmfrs `.GetType().GetProperty(text).GetValue(item)`, that's all reflection. You would still just use `List<Tuple<someType, anotherType>> x = ...; var selectListItems = x.ToSelectList()`

Comment: I am also getting 'IEnumerable<Tuple<int, string>>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync'

Comment: @egmfrs Where exactly are you getting that?

Comment: `.Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Id, x.Name)) .ToListAsync();` I only have .ToList() available.

Comment: @egmfrs You are either missing a `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` or you are not using `Select` on an `IQueryable<T>`

Comment: Sorted. I'm having to call it like this though, which is a bit a mouthful: `var mySelectList= (await _myService.GetItemsAsEnum()).ToSelectList<List<Tuple<int,string>>>();` instead of just being able to do `var mySelectList= (await _myService.GetItemsAsEnum()).ToSelectList();`

Answer (score -5):

You can either go for:

```
var myList = _myService.GetItems().Result.ToSelectList(nameof(MyEntity.Id));
```

but this will just block the thread and you will execute code non async

or change result of `_myService.GetItems()` to `List<SelectListItem>`.

Anyway what is the point of this async if you immediately need the result?

Comment: `async` means you won't block waiting for a response and won't waste a thread to wait for an IO/network call that doesn't use the CPU. It *allows* you to immediatelly use the result.

Comment: `.Result` though will block the caller and not just waste a thread, it will start by spinwaiting thus wasting CPU, before suspending the thread. That's not a bug, blocking is *not* supposed to take so long that the thread needs to be suspended

Comment: I thought async was best because it calls to the database. I'm not entirely sure. Is it useless?

Comment: @egmfrs This answer is completely wrong in every sense, please disregard it